# MS Access Import from Text File problems

Tags: ms-access, vba, database

I'm trying to import a text file into an access database. It's not one I've written myself but the spec for the delimited text file is set up properly and the file imports properly using the wizard. When I try to use the import functions of the app itself, the ImportError table tells "Field Truncation" for one of the fields. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the field in question have more than 255 characters? Does the Import Specification show this field as Memo? Are you importing to an existing table?

Comment: My guess is that the spec is *not* properly configured, but the Wizard corrects the oversight somehow. Are you loading the specification explicitly when you test with the Wizard? Have you resaved the spec that works under a new name and tried that one? And you might want to post your DoCmd.TransferText command -- maybe you've mixed up or omitted some of the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest examining each column that you're bringing in, and then measuring that against your table column properties in table "Design" mode.

Common things I've seen throw this error are:

1. Imported text exceeding the 255 character limit of a field (in which case you can change the field type to memo)
2. Date fields being set up as short date format, and then trying to import long dates/times into the field.
3. Text other than "yes/no/true/false" being imported into Yes/No/True/False fields.
4. Double-check your columns for similar names, and then check the data being imported. Sometimes when multiple people are working on a project and appending data, columns with similar names can get confused...especially if the column is collapsed so that its name is not entirely showing.

Comment: "Short date" is a display format, not a data storage format. Any valid date format in an import source will be properly imported and converted to Jet/ACE's date format (which is a double, where the integer part is the day from 12/30/1899 and the decimal part is the time). Formatting of the target field has no effect whatsoever on imports -- only the text representation of dates in the import source has an effect. If it's valid, Jet/ACE will import it correctly.